# align lines when pasting files in bash

Tags: bash, paste

How to align the rows (and use alphabetic sort) when pasting files into columns?

Example:

```
$ paste <(printf '%s\n' bike car lane road wheel) <(printf '%s\n' car rollers wheel) <(printf '%s\n' bike lane tire wheel) | column -s $'\t' -t
bike   car      bike
car    rollers  lane
lane   wheel    tire
road            wheel
wheel
```

and the desired output is:

```
bike            bike
car     car      
lane            lane
road             
        rollers  
                tire
wheel   wheel   wheel
```

Comment: Don't use `paste` for this. It combines files line by line, it doesn't match the contents. You might be able to do something with `awk`.

Comment: please update the question to explicitly describe how you're matching rows from the 3 data sets; is it based simply on the same exact spelling? what would be the expected output from `paste <(echo "HELLO") <(echo "hello")`? what about `paste <(echo a) <(echo 1)`?

Comment: will the first data set *always* contain all possible strings (as shown in the example)? or is it possible the first data set may not contrain a string and if so then how do you determine the order in which to display rows? will the inputs always be sorted and if not are supposed to (re)sort the output?

Comment: BTW, instead of using `echo -e`, consider `printf '%s\n' bike car lane road wheel`. [The POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) explicitly recommends using `printf` instead whenever one might be tempted to reach for either `-n` or backslash-escape sequences; [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) on [unix.se] goes into more details on why, but the _very_ short form is that `echo -e` is a nonstandard feature that, even in bash, is able to be disabled at runtime, including through the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what your looking for?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

awk -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR == 1 { ++FILENUM }
    { arr[$0] = arr[$0] FS FILENUM }
    END {
        for (key in arr)
            for (i = 1; i <= FILENUM; i++)
                printf( "%s%s", \
                    (index(arr[key]" ", " "i" ") ? key : "-" ), \
                    (i < FILENUM ? OFS : ORS) \
                )
    }
' <(printf '%s\n' bike car lane road wheel) \
  <(printf '%s\n' car rollers wheel) \
  <(printf '%s\n' bike lane tire wheel)
```

```
lane    -   lane
bike    -   bike
-   -   tire
wheel   wheel   wheel
car car -
-   rollers -
road    -   -
```

Comment: That's it. I'd rather save it as an `awk` script to easily call with as many input files as desired.

Comment: @LEo defining a shell function might also be handy: `myfun() { awk '…' "$@"; }` . Then you call it with as many file arguments that you want `myfun file1 file2 … fileN`

Answer (score 0):

To align the rows

```bash
$ paste file1 file2 | column -t
```

If you want to make the output easier to read, you can also specify the delimiter to use when pasting. Like a comma or tab.

```bash
$ paste -d '\t' file1 file2 | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adaptation of @fravadona's answer using array of array and putting it in an awk script.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
FNR == 1 { ++FILENUM }
{ arr[$0][FILENUM] = $0 }
END {
    for (ln in arr)
         for (i = 1; i <= FILENUM; i++)
             printf ( "%s%s", \
                 (length(arr[ln][i]) > 0 ? arr[ln][i] : "-"), \
                 (i < FILENUM ? OFS : ORS) \
             )
}
```

Execution example:

```bash
./myscript.awk <(printf '%s\n' bike car lane road wheel) \
               <(printf '%s\n' car rollers wheel) \
               <(printf '%s\n' bike lane tire wheel) 
lane    -       lane
bike    -       bike
-       -       tire
wheel   wheel   wheel
car     car     -
-       rollers -
road    -       -
```